# Restore Database failed for Server

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008-r2, smo, database-restore

Using this I successfully back up my database:

```
Server myServer = new Server(@"PC-1\INSTANCE1");   
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                Backup bkpDBFull = new Backup();
                bkpDBFull.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
                bkpDBFull.Database = "MyDatabase";
                BackupDeviceItem bkpDevice = new BackupDeviceItem(saveFileDialog1.FileName, DeviceType.File);
                bkpDBFull.Devices.Add(bkpDevice);
                bkpDBFull.BackupSetName = "Sample";
                bkpDBFull.BackupSetDescription = "Sample";
                bkpDBFull.SqlBackup(myServer);
            }
        }
        catch (SmoException ex)
        {
            throw new SmoException(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
        }
    }
```

But I got an error in my restore `Restore failed for Server 'PC-1\INSTANCE1'.`

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Restore restoreDB = new Restore();
            restoreDB.Database = "MyDatabase";
            restoreDB.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
            BackupDeviceItem bkpDevice = new BackupDeviceItem(openFileDialog1.FileName, DeviceType.File);
            restoreDB.Devices.Add(bkpDevice);
            restoreDB.ReplaceDatabase = true;
            restoreDB.SqlRestore(myServer);
        }
    }
```

I use the same server in both backup and restore. Why it failed in restore although the backup is successful using the same server and database?

Comment: What does it say in the SQL server error log?  It could be that because there are connections open to the database when you try the restore, it cannot get exclusive access and then the restore fails.

Comment: Restore failed for Server 'PC-1\INSTANCE1'. SSMS is closed during the operation.

Comment: Restoring database width databasename that already exists may cause this issue as well.

Comment: There should be an InnerException or prior Log Entry that gives additional explanation of the reason for the failure.  (Although if I had to guess, I'd go with trying to overwrite an in use DB or DB File).

Comment: Is the error related to tail log backup?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to rule out is it not liking the hyphen in the machine name, which you're not supposed to do really.
If you try using the IP address as the server name this should rule this out.

More likely to be a database in use thing as others have said.